# How to check if a string ends with only a specific value using REGEX

Tags: regex

I am trying to find if a particular string ends with only a specific word and **no words are after that**

strings i subjecting to searching:

`1.) https://beta-qa.pearson.com/iie-api/courses/5daa3022e4b0ef7dce37acec/assignments`

`2.) https://beta-qa.pearson.com/iie-api/courses/5daa3022e4b0ef7dce37acec/assignments/984fa00d-d002-4826-80f4-76d1267e3aaa`

What I want is to only get the string that ends with assignment **(i.e. the `first string` from the above two examples)**

This is the `regexes` I was using: **`*\[assignments]$`**, **`\assignments/$`**

This is not working this gives both results. How can I only filter the string **that ends with assignments**?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `assignments$`. No backslashes, no classes.

Comment: Which programming language are you using for this task?

Comment: @Biffen: Thank you, what if I need to to show only results that ends in the pattern `"/assignments/some-id-number"` what would be the regex? `some-id-number` is a number.

Comment: @JananathBanuka See [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

The correct regexp for this is `assignments$`. It probably didn't work for you because you mixed `/` and `\` in your last regex.

UPD: See an example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KvWXc6/1)

Comment: Thank you, what if I need to to show only results that ends in the pattern `"/assignments/some-id-number"` what would be the regex? `some-id-number` is a number.

Comment: then it would be `assignments/\d+$`

Comment: What if to search a pattern like this? `/assignments/984fa00d-d002-4826-80f4-76d1267e3aa` that value after assignments is a combination of `numbers`, `characters` and a special `symbol`?

Comment: then it would be `assignments/[a-fA-F0-9-]+$`